# Centering the text in an imaged commandLink

Tags: css, jsf, commandlink

i have a p:commandLink with

```
.button{
    background-image: url(http://www.lefinnois.net/aqua/aqua1.jpg);
    display:inline-block;
    width:150;
    height:50;   
}
<p:commandLink update="media" value="Ok"
    action="#{productView.save}" styleClass="button">
</p:commandLink>
```

it is ok i have an imaged button.

but i want "Ok" text to take in place in the middle of the button image

what is your advice, i have tried something but no response so far.

i think it must be possible, if jsf is a web propramming platform.

**SOLVED**

i have to add padding to outside object to locate the inside object.

the code in the end:

```
.button{
        background-image: url(http://www.lefinnois.net/aqua/aqua1.jpg);
        display:inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:10px;//you must set it according to the height of image
        width:150;
        height:50;   
    }
```

Comment: `padding-top` is a bad approach to center vertically. The position is this way dependent on font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSS `text-align` property to `center` and set the `line-height` to the same height as element's height:

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
```

Don't forget to fix your `width` and `height` values to include the dimensions.

```
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
```

Comment: That's correct. Do you also want to center vertically? You wasn't clear on that. Just set `line-height` to the same height as the element. I've updated the answer.

Comment: if i understand right, i pass `height` value to `line-height` and it vertically centers the text. am i right?

Comment: Uh no, you can't pass variables around in CSS or something like that. Just set `line-height` to the same value as `height`. See also the example in my answer. Only in CSS frameworks like LESS and SASS you can use variables in CSS.

Comment: Hi  @BalusC. I have a problem about jsf s CSS logic, maybe pure CSS logic but i should ask here. The width is "button"s image width, am i right, but height which is also same as line-height is "line's height". How do we write these width and height properties within same curly brackets as if they define the same "object"(text line or button image background)?